# Inheriting properties, setter not synthetized when readwrite in inherited property from readonly

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, inheritance

I discovered a strange behaviour when working with a property, that was inherited as readonly and than redeclared in the inherited class as readwrite

In **A.h**

```
@interface A : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSObject * someProperty;

@end
```

In **B.h**

```
@interface B : A

// no matter if here
// @property (nonatomic, strong, readwrite) NSObject * someProperty;

- (void)foo;

@end
```

In **B.m**

```
@interface B()

// no matter if here
@property (nonatomic, strong, readwrite) NSObject * someProperty;

@end

@implementation B

- (void)foo {

    NSLog(@"%@", self.someProperty);

    // crash here with unrecognized selector setSomeProperty:
    self.someProperty = [NSObject new];
}

@end
```

calling

```
self.someProperty = [NSObject new];
```

**causes the code to crash on unrecognized selector "setSomeProperty:"**

investigation showed, that it looks like the setter did not get synthetized, even when declared as readwrite

**Why is this happening? The compiler didnt indicate any warning for this to happen, nor i found anywhere this behaviour documented**

Answer (score 2):

Add a `@synthesize` directive to the B.m file and the crash will go away:

```
@synthesize someProperty = _someProperty;
```

The problem is that since in the parent class you declared the property as `readonly` there is no setter synthesized for it. And the subclasses inherit this behavior. Even if you redeclare the property to be `readwrite` in the subclass. 
The `@synthesize` command will instruct the compiler to generate the accessor methods for class B again.

Hope this helps!

[image]

Comment: Did you try this? I get "error: property 'someProperty' attempting to use instance variable '_someProperty' declared in super class 'A'"

Comment: Yes I tried it. If I don't add the synthesize directive to the B.m file I get: "unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xec74a00". If then I add it and re-run the app the error goes away.

Comment: Strange, my results are different, perhaps I made some error ... Did you define the superclass with the property in the same way as in the question?

Comment: Maybe there's something else going on... I'll investigate further

Comment: This is a subtle issue where the compiler is letting the OP down. This doesn't solve the problem, it *masks* it. @MartinR is correct in his reasoning - the compiler cannot (given the design of Obj-C) synthesise a setter to match the inherited getter. When you add an `@synthesize` to `B` the compiler implements both setter *and* a getter - and that getter does not call the inherited version. Now depending on how the compiler implements the backing store for a synthesised property and on how the inherited getter is written then it may work, you may get errors, or it may just malfunction.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot give you an official reference, but this is what I experienced: For a property *inherited from a superclass*, the compiler *does not generate* any accessor methods.

In your case, the property is declared as `readonly` in class A, so that the compiler creates
only a getter method. The re-declaration in class B does not create any additional accessor
methods. The reason might be that class B does not know "how" the property is realised in class A (it need not be an instance variable).

So the property declaration in the subclass is only a "promise" to the compiler that
getter and setter functions will be available at runtime (similar to a @dynamic declaration).
If there is no setter then you will get a runtime exception.

So a use case of re-declaring the property in the subclass would be if the superclass 
declares the property as read-only in the *public* interface, but as read-write in the
(*private*) class extension:

```
// A.h
@interface A : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSObject * someProperty;
@end

// A.m
@interface A()
@property (nonatomic, strong, readwrite) NSObject * someProperty;
@end

@implementation A
@end
```

In this case, both setter and getter are created in the class A, and class B 
can re-declare the property as read-write in its implementation.

Comment: This reasoning makes sense. Further as the compiler knows that it doesn't know how the property is realised it could issue a warning to the effect that a setter must be implemented or inherited. Maybe one of you should submit a radar?

Comment: @CRD: That is a good suggestion and thanks for the feedback. But since my answer and  LuisCien's answer somehow contradict each other, I will wait for some feedback from the OP first.

Comment: Martin, your reasoning does make sense. I've just run a test to confirm that the compiler (I used Xcode 4.6.3) is not being over clever and using information it shouldn't have access to by the design of the language - and it isn't. (Try setting `_someProperty` directly in `A`'s `init` and logging it in `B`'s `init` when there is an `@synthesize` - or use "Generate Assembler".) It's a subtle corner where the compiler is letting the OP down.